# Altering the appearance of cflayout tabs in CF9

Tags: css, coldfusion

I'm trying to overide the default appearance of cflayout tabs.

By putting an edited background sprite into the website images folder I can alter the hover appearance, but I cannot seem to get the text to turn white on hover by referencing the built in .x-tab-strip-over class.

In action [here](http://camarillon.com/test.cfm)

```
    <style type="text/css">
    div.x-tab-panel-header, ul.x-tab-strip-top {
        background-image: none;
        background-color: transparent;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
    }
    div.x-tab-panel-header {
        border: 0px;
    }
    .x-tab-strip-active, .x-tab-strip-text {
        font-weight: normal !important;
        font-size: 14px !important;
        font-family: arial !important;
    }
    .x-tab-strip-over {
        color: white !important;
    }
    .x-tab-right, .x-tab-left, .x-tab-strip-inner {
        background-image: url(images/xd-tabs-sprite.gif) !important;
    }
</style>

<cflayout type="tab">
    <cflayoutarea title="Mouse">
        Mickey Mouse
    </cflayoutarea>
    <cflayoutarea title="Duck">
        Donald Duck
    </cflayoutarea>
</cflayout>
```

Any clues appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
.x-tab-panel-header .x-tab-strip-over span {
    color: white;
}
.x-tab-panel-header .x-tab-strip-over.x-tab-strip-active span {
    color: red;
}
```

There's a lot going on in there, so I just tested until I found something that worked.

Comment: Yep, I feel a slightly dirty fix but that did it :-)

Answer (score 3):

CF9 uses ExtJS 3.x while Cf8 uses ExtJS 2.x

> How to use:
>
> 1. Click Ext Theme Builder.
> 2. Select Template (blue or gray) in the top toolbar (i recommend - gray)
> 3. Select Base Color, Header Color, Background color, Border color, Header
>      Font, Font, Window transparency,
>      Toolset (Default, Vista,
>      TargetProcess, Graphite)  and ExtJS
>      version. Unselected Border color will
>      be assigned automatically according to
>      base color
> 4. Click Apply
> 5. Enter Theme name
> 6. Click Download Theme. It will be xtheme-Theme name.zip file

http://extbuilder.dynalias.com/springapp/mainpage.htm